# Sort images based on age

Tags: python, mat, imdb

I'm using the following code to load the **IMDB** [dataset](https://data.vision.ee.ethz.ch/cvl/rrothe/imdb-wiki/) and **mat** file then isolate them based on the ages. The following code loads the mat file and then it computes the age by subtracting the data in which the photo was taken from the date of birth

```
from scipy.io import loadmat
from datetime import datetime
import os
import  numpy as np
from shutil import copy
db = "imdb"
mat_path = "data/{}_crop/{}.mat".format(db, db)
print (mat_path)
dataset = loadmat(mat_path)
face_score_treshold = 3
path_root = "data/{}_crop/".format(db)
def calc_age(taken, dob):
    birth = datetime.fromordinal(max(int(dob) - 366, 1))

    # assume the photo was taken in the middle of the year
    if birth.month < 7:
        return taken - birth.year
    else:
        return taken - birth.year - 1


image_names_array = dataset['imdb']['full_path'][0, 0][0]
dob = dataset[db][0, 0]["dob"][0]  # Matlab serial date number
photo_taken = dataset[db][0, 0]["photo_taken"][0]  # year
image_names = []
age = [calc_age(photo_taken[i], dob[i]) for i in range(len(dob))]
print(age)

for image_name_arg in range(image_names_array.shape[0]):
    try:
        os.makedirs(str (age[image_name_arg]))
    except OSError:
        pass
    copy(path_root + "/" + str(image_names_array[image_name_arg][0]),str (age[image_name_arg]))
    image_name = image_names_array[image_name_arg][0]
    image_names.append(image_name)
    print( dict(zip(image_names, age)))
```

After calculating the age, it creates the folder with age as the folder name and it copies the image files to the folder.

However there are lots of false negatives in the resulting folder. How can I be able to sort this out?

Comment: What do you mean false negatives? This is not a classification question, it's a question regarding sorting

Comment: Can you please reduce this to a [mcve]? This code has readability issues.

Comment: ya sure.........

Comment: [Edit] your Question and show at least 3 Lines of Data from `print(age)` and `print(image_names_array)` and `print(image_names_array.shape[0])`.